# How to know if a user blocked himself from PWA notifications in Angular

Tags: angular, push-notification, notifications, progressive-web-apps

I have added PWA to my existing application using the NGSW and SwPush libraries (I am using angular 8). I have an unsubscribe button to unsubscribe from getting notifications. If the user unsubscribes himself using this button then I am calling an HTTP Post call that removes his subscription from the DB.

There is also a way to remove yourself from notifications using the browser. I want to know how I can tell if the user unsubscribed himself that way so I can remove his subscription object from the DB.

[image: Removing notifications from browser]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Notification.permission` to check permission in browser. See documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/permission.

Also, you can subscribe for browser permissions change like this:

```js
if ('permissions' in navigator) {    
  navigator.permissions.query({name:'notifications'})
    .then((permission) => {
      permission.onchange = () => {
        //...        
      };
    });
}
```

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PermissionStatus/onchange

Comment: I tried to listen to permission.onChage and added console.log but every time I changed the permissions nothing happened. the only thing that I got was a request to reload the page.